# In Python, how do I create lists based on a user inputted number?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a classic card game in Python based on a users input. I want to ask them > `players = int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 '))`

and depending if they say 2.

```
players = [[], []] will be created
```

but if they said 3

```
then players = [[], [], []] would be created
```

etc

so far all i can do is players [[], [], [], []] which means 4 players must always play the game??

Answer (score 1):

You could do,

```
n = input("number: ")    # n = 2 say
out = [list() for i in range(n)] # [[], []]
```

See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
players = [ [] for x in range(int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 ')))]
```

<strike>`players = int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 '))`

    `players = [[]] * players`</strike>

Comment: Well, now try to append something to the first sub-list.

Comment: you can do `players[0].append("hello")`

Comment: And then print the whole list. You'll be surprised :)

Comment: Additionally, I don't think it's a great idea to reuse the name `players` for both the input from the user (which is a number) and the container (which is a list). Try to use meaningful names, especially in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
players = [[] for i in range(int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 ')))]
```

Output:

```
>>> players = [[] for i in range(int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 ')))]
How many players are playing? 2-4 3
>>> players
[[], [], []]
```

Or you can use the `*` operator:

```
players = [[]] * int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 '))
```

However, changing an element in the list when using second method would cause every sublist to change too. So for you the list comprehension method would be better.

E.g:

```
>>> players = [[]] * int(input('How many players are playing? 2-4 '))
How many players are playing? 2-4 3
>>> players
[[], [], []]
>>> players[1].append("hello")
>>> players
[['hello'], ['hello'], ['hello']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say:

```
vectorPlayers = []

players = int(input("'How many players are playing? 2-4 '"))

for x in range(players):
    vectorPlayers.append([])


print(vectorPlayers)
```

This will create a vector with an empty vector in every position